# Multiple "kworker" are hogging CPU. Possible virus?

Tags: performance, crashes

I read that it is used on the computer.

It has been coming up on my Samsung Galaxy S2. It is on at least 3 times at once and up to 7 or 8 at once. They are called `kworker/0:1` through `kworker/0:4` and/or `kworker/u:1` through `kworker/u:4`

Occasionally, it comes up as using about 80 % of the CPU. My phone also regularly crashes as of recently. Could kworker be the problem?

The virus I have also is kind of trojan-based and has popups when I restart my phone sometimes. Also, when my phone is asleep, and I turn it back on, it says kworker is using 100% of my CPU data.

Comment: `kworker*` is a kernel thread. You will find them on every modern Linux kernel.

Answer (score 6):

Uhhhh, **that** is not a virus! *Who told you that?* :)

`kworker` is part of the Linux Kernel's scheduler in which it manages the processes running and switching to it a la multitasking.

That is normal behaviour of the kernel! It exists on the desktop linux also, see this example to illustrate:

```
ps -elf | grep kworker
1 S root         5     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker Jan31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
1 S root         6     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker Jan31 ?        00:00:23 [kworker/u:0]
1 S root         7     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker Jan31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:0H]
1 S root        16     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker Jan31 ?        00:00:16 [kworker/1:0]
1 S root        17     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker Jan31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
1 S root        22     2  0  60 -20 -     0 worker Jan31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
```

The reason that it is "*using about 80 % of the CPU*" is that there's some apps running that are consuming a lot of CPU cycles.

All in all, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138166/discussion-on-answer-by-t0mm13b-galaxy-s2-cellphone-problem-possible-virus).

Answer (score 3):

Even if it might only cover a part of your question: Don't let you scare by those "virus" marketing bluff. There is no such thing as a virus on Android, and hardly will be.

[image: virus]

Sure some companies want to sell you their "anti virus product". But if you take a deeper look at what it really does (apart from the marketing buzzwords), none of them seems to really deal with viruses (how should they, if there are none?).

So what's the thing behind it?

Mixing of terms. Today far to many people taking "virus" as the "master-term" including all kinds of malware: virii themselves, trojans, and other evil doers. The [Wikipedia article on the term "computer virus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) starts right away with the most important fact:

> A computer virus is a computer program that can replicate itself and spread from one computer to another.

Ever heard of such a thing on Android? No, here the user has to explicitly install it, and agree to its requested permissions. So how should this spread itself? (Malicious gossip has it these terms apply to the Windows OS and most of its payed programs: they replicate and spread from computer to computer via file sharing...). So *Wikipedia* continues:

> The term "virus" is also commonly, but erroneously, used to refer to other types of malware, including but not limited to adware and spyware programs that do not have a reproductive ability.

There you go: You don't have a virus.

Comment: Perfect! +1 from me, have been telling the OP that all along and OP insisted to a point in which OP started flaming me by name-calling (which was removed by mods). Thank you for that answer!

Comment: You're very welcome, @t0mm13b ! I've read all the comments above and I guess I added the right solution in my comment there, don't you think? ;)

Comment: ;) Yep! Why you think I gave you +1, if I could I'd give you 5 +1's but... SE does not allow you to that!!! :)

Comment: Yeah, tnx @t0mm13b -- but I was actually cross-referencing to my comment on the question itself, at the end of your long "conversation". Which you meanwhile found :)